# istream::read not reading whole file

Tags: c++, file

I am practising on filereading which is why I made this 'Hex editor' which uses the read function to supposedly copy the file in memory.

```
ifstream iFile(argv[1],ios::ate, ios::binary);

int sizea=iFile.tellg();
char* file=new char[sizea];

iFile.seekg(0);
iFile.read(file,sizea);

cout << iFile.gcount();
```

So for my testfile, the sizea is set to 2378, the proper block of 2378 bytes in memory is allocated but the gcount() function returns 389. Indeed, the memory is filled up to the 389th byte with correct information and it's full of CD s until the 2378th byte.

Has the read function have an internal limit of some sorts? I can't see what else I might be doing wrong here.

OK, problem found:

```
ifstream iFile(argv[1],ios::ate, ios::binary);
//should be
ifstream iFile(argv[1],ios::ate | ios::binary);
```

Comment: You forgot to seek to the end first?

Comment: What position is the file pointer when you execute `tellg()`?

Comment: it's set at the end of the file. edited with the ifstream definition. I also made some tests and it seems that the failbit is set after the read. further testing shows that the read function stops copying to memory when it finds 1a hex value in my file.